# blank page - echo data from mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code but after I run it, I see a blank picture; why?
I'm trying to create a myaccount page that shows the information of my user.

```php
if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
    $uid=  get_current_user();
    $sql = "SELECT uid, first,last,sem,email FROM user WHERE uid='$uid'";
    $cursor = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); // for example
    $result = mysqli_fetch_row($cursor);
    $n = mysqli_num_fields($cursor);
    while ($result) {
        for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $val= $result[$i];
            echo "$val,";
        }
        echo '<br>';
        $result = mysqli_fetch_row($cursor);
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem, before asking us?

Comment: Try to add else condition and echo something to know that if there is any error in your SESSION.

Comment: I have a else, that echo "You are not logged in". I dont know what other to try

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$sql = "SELECT uid, first,last,sem,email FROM user WHERE uid='$uid'";
$cursor = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // for example
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($cursor);
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_row($cursor)) {

    print_r($result);

    echo '<br>';


}


$conn->close();
```

}

Comment: the same thing, blank

Comment: $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];

Comment: the same with $uid = $_SESSION['uid']; Blank page. I have tried your code but blank again. if i echo $uid after $uid = $_SESSION['uid']; its ok, i see my username

Comment: check your database uid = ? in your database ? put manually .. its also maybe problem your session maintain .. please print_r($_SESSION)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your $_SESSION['uid'] is not set? Try echo it out.

Comment: the same with $uid = $_SESSION['uid']; Blank page.. if i echo $uid after $uid = $_SESSION['uid']; its ok, i see my username

Comment: I understand, so it forked right. Can you please describe table definition? It might throw exception if your $uid is integer. Try this syntax: `$sql = 'SELECT uid, first,last,sem,email FROM user WHERE uid="'.$uid.'"';` instead.